# Equivalence relations--prove R/~ is homeomorphic to R

Tags: general-topology

On $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology, generate an equivalence relation by $x\sim x$ for all $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$ and $x\sim 0$ for all $x$ in $[0,1]$.
Prove $\mathbb{R}/\sim$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.

I'm totally lost on this. I'm supposed to be proving that there is a homeomorphism but I don't understand how that is possibly true considering $f:[0,1]\ \longrightarrow \{0\}$ is not injective.